# MongoDb aggregation project onto collection

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I've a problem with a huge MongoDb aggregation pipeline. I've many constraint and I've simplified the problem a lot. Hence, don't discuss the goal for this query.

I've a mongo aggregation that gives something similar to this:

```
[
  {
    "content": {
      "processes": [
        {
          "id": "101a",
          "title": "delivery"
        },
        {
          "id": "101b",
          "title": "feedback"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

To this intermediate result **I'm forced** to apply a **project** operation in order to obtain something similar to this:

```
[  
  {
    "results":
    {
      "titles": [
        {
          "id": "101a",
          "value": "delivery"
        },
        {
          "id": "101b",
          "value": "feedback"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
enter code here
```

But applying this projections:

```
  "results.titles.id": "$content.processes.id",
  "results.titles.value": "$content.processes.title"
```

I obtain this:

```
[  
  {
    "results":
    {
      "titles": {
          "id": ["101a", "101b"]
          "value": ["delivery", "feedback"]
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Collection are created but not in the proper position.
Is it possible to exploit some operator **inside the project operation** in order to tell mongo to create an array in a parent position?

Something like this:

```
"results.titles.$[x].value" : "$content.processes.value"
```

Comment: try this `{
    "$project": {
      "results.titles": "$content.processes"
    }
  }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the dot notation to project entire array:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            "results.titles": "$content.processes"
        }
    }
])
```

and if you need to rename `title` to `value` then you have to apply [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) operator:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            "results.titles": {
                $map: {
                    input: "$content.processes",
                    as: "process",
                    in: {
                        id: "$$process.id",
                        value: "$$process.title"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```